# windows10 doesn't see the CD/DVD disk

Tags: windows-10

Windows-10 does not see the CD/DVD disk. It does see the drive D: but now it doesn't see a blank disk. It will see and play a burned CD or DVD but not a blank one. I cannot Burn a disk. The burner app says load a disk.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: It is one question with several symptoms. I have listed symptoms with the question.

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted several times. I have tried different CDs and different DVDs. No help.